# pivot queries using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I have one databases with two tables I need to interact with. The first table is a members table (`login`), that has their id (`id`), first name (`given_name`), and last name (`family_name`). The second table holds the persons login or member id (`mid`) their clock in (`dateTimeIn`) and clock out (`dateTimeOut`) date time in an ISO 8601 string, and the types of activity (`type`) that they can do. `dateTimeIn` & `dateTimeOut` are both ISO 8601 date time fields, `type`, `id`, `mid`, `given_name` and `family_name` are all strings. The remote foreign key that binds these two tables is `hours.mid` that maps directory to the `login.id` column.

`login` table:

`CREATE TABLE login(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, given_name TEXT NOT NULL, family_name TEXT NOT NULL, lastseen INTEGER NOT NULL)`

```
id                   |given_name|family_name
-----------------------------------------------
103673125444466670779|Mark      |Tomlin
```

`hours` table:

`CREATE TABLE hours(mid TEXT, type TEXT, dateTimeIn INTEGER, dateTimeOut INTEGER)`

```
mid                  |type    |dateTimeIn      |dateTimeOut
-----------------------------------------------------------------
103673125444466670779|Meeting |2013-06-04T20:00|2013-06-04T21:00
103673125444466670779|Meeting |2013-06-10T20:00|2013-06-10T21:00
103673125444466670779|Crew    |2013-06-21T22:00|2013-06-22T13:00
103673125444466670779|Crew    |2013-06-22T23:00|2013-06-23T07:00
103673125444466670779|Training|2013-06-23T20:00|2013-06-23T21:00
103673125444466670779|Crew    |2013-06-29T23:00|2013-06-30T07:00
103673125444466670779|Detail  |2013-06-23T17:00|2013-06-23T19:00
103673125444466670779|Meeting |2013-06-25T14:00|2013-06-25T18:00
103673125444466670779|Detail  |2013-06-28T01:00|2013-06-28T08:00
103673125444466670779|Crew    |2013-06-28T19:00|2013-06-28T23:00
```

What I am looking for is a query that will give me this table below for any date range that I give it. For example, for the month of June 2013 it should produce something like this. If I had more people in login, then it would add them below as well, sorted by lastname, first name.

```
given_name|family_name|Crew|Meeting|Detail|Training
Mark      |Tomlin     |35  |6      |9     |1
```

Another query that would be awesome is if I could get a year view, with each member that is added, they become a new row.

```
given_name|family_name|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec
Mark      |Tomlin     |35 |62 |27 |12 |88 |35 | - | - | - | - | - | -
```

Comment: `Getting the hours each person has done`-- inspired by *the lives of others*?

Comment: Sorry, unable to recall what you're referring to.

Comment: I figured, I'm going to delete my comments now, I hope you'll do the same.

Comment: What have you tried? With what particular aspect of these queries do you have problems? Filtering by date? Computing a time interval? Aggregating values? Sorting?

Comment: Well, for one thing, I have no idea how to pivot a table. So I'm looking that information up now. I was not really sure how to do it in the first place or even if it were possible but I started reading as many manuals as I could find on SQL as pertains to SQLite. I was having problems initially, calculating the number of hours each member did within a month, but I finally managed to fix that with this query. `SELECT type, SUM(strftime('%s', dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', dateTimeIn)) AS Time FROM hours GROUP BY type, mid;` But now I need to pivot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did need a query that would give me a list of all of the current hours for everyone within the current month. I did that with the following query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    hours
WHERE
    dateTimeIn BETWEEN date('now', 'start of month') AND date('now', 'start of month','+1 month','-1 day');
```

I first found a query that showed me how to give the general appearance of a pivot. From there, I hacked away at it until I found an option that worked for what I was trying to do.

This query gives me the total for each member as number of seconds within the database.

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.given_name,
    m.family_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Crew' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Crew,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Detail' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Detail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Meeting' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Meeting,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Training' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Training
FROM login m JOIN hours h ON m.id = h.mid
GROUP BY m.id;
```

I can then augment this to only give me a running total for the current month as well.

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.given_name,
    m.family_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Crew' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Crew,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Detail' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Detail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Meeting' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Meeting,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.type = 'Training' THEN strftime('%s', h.dateTimeOut) - strftime('%s', h.dateTimeIn) END) Training
FROM login m JOIN hours h ON m.id = h.mid
WHERE
    dateTimeIn BETWEEN date('now', 'start of month') AND date('now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day')
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Now I just need to do the last one to show the running total for the year.